# WildCard it does't work properly

Tags: angular

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
import { RouterModule, Route } from"@angular/router";
import {CarsListComponent} from "./cars/cars-list/cars-list.component";
import {AuthGuard} from "./auth/auth.guard";
import {PageNotFoundComponent} from "./shared-module/page-not-found/page- 
not-found.component";
import {LoginModule} from "./login/login.module"

const APP_ROUTES : Route[] = [

    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'cars', canActivate: 
[AuthGuard] },

    { path: 'cars', component: <any>CarsListComponent, canActivate: 
[AuthGuard]},

    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

];



@NgModule({
    imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(APP_ROUTES, { enableTracing: true})
    ],
    exports: []
})


export class AppRoutingModule{}
```

Hello

I have problem with wildcard. I created new component PageNotFoundComponent and when I add this on my app.module.ts, this wildcard loads first I dont know why?

Thanks for help

Comment: could you share code of AuthGaurd?

Comment: What does your console say?

Comment: On website console and my Cmder everything its okey, 0 errors

Comment: Also, what's the purpose of having an `AuthGuard` on your default route?

Comment: What's the url your trying to access? Also when the `AuthGuard` get's triggered do you do any redirecting? I suspect your default route is `''` that is guarded is causing an issue. How are you to authenticate to a page that requires authentication first?

Comment: When you go in my site you have to log on. So when you will enter localhost:4200, site route you on localhost:4200/login, and you can't go on localhost/etc becouse i have this authguard.

Answer (score 0):

you just have one route which is guarded when router scans the routes it does not find any match so it's routing to pagenotfound
You need to define a default route  If the user isn’t authenticated, they should re-routed to some other place you can define a route `/login`  which should not be guarded

```
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const APP_ROUTES : Routes = [

    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'login'},
    { path: 'login', component:logincomponent },

    { path: 'cars', component: CarsListComponent, canActivate: 
[AuthGuard]},

    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }

];
```

Comment: hmm i saw this before but when i change on routes i have error on my code

Comment: What error are you getting update your question accordingly?

Comment: @MarekPatyna didn't I rectify it in my solution observe closely,you need to define an array of routes not route[]=[....]

Comment: @MarekPatyna don't add error in the answer instead update your question

Comment: Now i see, sorry my mistake, but wildcard still loads first

Comment: remove authguard from first route and see

Comment: Still same hmmm

Comment: <any> in the second route, What's the purpose of it? remove it

Comment: i removed <any> and authguard and still same, no idea

Comment: Also, any definite routes should come before your wildcard and default routes, so switch `cars` to be the top item in the routes array.

Comment: @MarekPatyna I have updated my answer see if this works

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
const APP_ROUTES : Route[] = [
    { path: '', pathMatch: 'full', redirectTo: 'cars'
    },    
    { path: 'cars', component: CarsListComponent
    },
    { path: '404', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    { path: '**', redirectTo: '404' }

];
```

Comment: I am now being redirected to localhost:4200/404 when i write local only localhost:4200

Comment: Try removing the AuthGuard

Comment: Still same no idea